# Using Log4net with a Google App Engine Backend

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine, logging, log4net

I have an application (written in C#) that uses Log4net to gather events locally. Now I would like to add remote logging so that I can aggregate event monitoring. One possibility is to use GAE to host the aggregate service; however, I can't find any solid place to start. Can anyone point me in the right direction? how can I remotely send logs to a Google App Engine Back-end?

Note: I would like to use Python or Java to build the host, since I have very little skill in Go, and None in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a custom appender. Just like there is an appender that writes to a log file you need to tell Log4Net how to log to GAE. Here is an example on code project:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/406634/Creating-a-custom-log4net-appender

HTH,
Eric

Comment: Duh, i can't believe i didn't think of this earlier... Thanks.

Comment: Hehe no problem, I just happen to be working on something very similar otherwise I wouldn't have known either.